# equality of inverse function on measure

Tags: measure-theory

Good morning. That is the question:

Let C be a collection of all sets E that $f^{-1}(E)$ is measurable.

So $f^{-1}(E^{c}) = (f^{-1}(E))^{c}$, is true?

In fact, i want to know if the equality is true, the firt part of the question is a help for one who's try to help. This frase appear in the first part of the solution of the question:

Let f be measurable and B a Borel set. Then, $f^{-1}(B)$ is a measurable set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does $A^c$ denote the complement set of $A$?
If so the equality is true even if $f$ is not measurable as a [consequence of the definition of the inverse image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Consequences).

About your last statement: note that if $f$ is measurable then for every measurable set $B$ $f^{-1}(B)$ is measurable by [definition of a measurable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_function#Formal_definition).